# Signle-product thumbnails size woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, thumbnails

I'm using woocommerce to build my website .My single product page is showing thumbs in a very ugly way .
If any one can help me how to fix this i'll be thankful ....

I'm not a css professional so,if you can tell me the steps will be better for a beginner like me .

[My page you can see error your self](http://mazayait.com/slinks/product/single-disc/)
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto - WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display
Here locate the products settings you can customize as you want.

Also you can see video demo on below link

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/

Comment: I did that with no success .